# Display a .doc file with header and footer in iPhone

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator

I want to display a .doc file with header and footer in iPhone. Currently I'm using a webview to display the file. I'm able to display the file, but the header and footer of the .doc file is not displayed in the webview.

To show the .doc file I used the following code.

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"a" ofType:@"doc"];
    NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
    [pdfWebView_ loadRequest:request];
```

How do I display the .doc file with a header and a footer?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in customize way ie.you can add  UILabel or UIImageView in place of header & footer of your UIView & In between that UILabels add UIWebView.

Comment: That will be a good option if I've to display only one .doc file. currently I'm thinking of displaying some 50-60 files. So a function to find the header and footer will be needed. I think there will be some better fix for this problem.